# Android ListView ClassCastException

Tags: android, listview, exception, ads

I want to integrate ads inside a ListView and I have the following code:

**UPDATED AdViewHelper.java**

```
  public LinearLayout configureAdViewWithLayoutContainer(final Activity context) {

    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    PublisherAdView adView = new PublisherAdView(context);
    adView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.google_ads_width),
            context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.google_ads_height)));
    adView.setId(R.id.ad_view_id);
    adView.setAdUnitId("MY_UNIT_ID");
    adView.setAdSizes(getAdSize(context));
    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final PublisherAdView finalAdView = adView;
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            finalAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
        }
    });
    adView.setAppEventListener(this);

    layout.addView(adView);

    return layout;
}
```

In the **MyAdapter.java**

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (getItemViewType(position) == AD_TYPE) {
     return adViewHelper.configureAdViewWithLayoutContainer(activity);    
 } else {
      return convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Note: Please ignore the ViewHolder and recycling. It's not the purpose of this question.

So, the problem is that I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
        at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1826)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know that this is because my PublisherAdView is inside a LinearLayout, but I need that LinearLayout in order to make the visibility of ad to work (when the user opens the screen the ad row should be hidden until is loaded).

How can I still use the LinearLayout and yet get rid of this class cast exception?

Comment: change `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` with `AbsListView.LayoutParams`. Remember that the LayoutParams object refers always to the parent

Comment: I already tried that, but I still get this exception.

Comment: you mean on this line: `layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams`?

Comment: Yes. This is the code: layout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: this `adView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(` should take LinearLayout.LayoutParams since is direct child of a LinearLayout

Comment: I tried that now, but still not working :(

Comment: Laura, take a look at my answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens here:

```
layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

`layout` is used in ListView, so it should have AbsListView.LayoutParams

Then here:

```
adView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
        context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.google_ads_width),
        context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.google_ads_height)));
```

Your `layout` is a LinearLayout, so its children should have LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

So you basically did it vice versa now :)

Comment: Post a full stacktrace, please.

Comment: I figured out where my mistake was thanks to your suggestion. I was using the adView in another part of the code also and for some reason I had to add there the layoutParams. Thanks!